# Nested if Statement not working

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am trying to write the code for finding a leap year. However, there seems to be something wrong with the nested `if` and `else` format. Please suggest.

```
[int]$x = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input a year : ';

if ($x % 4 -eq 0) {
    Write-Host $x 'is a leap year';
    if ($x % 100 -eq 0) {
        Write-Host $x 'is a leap year';
        if ($x % 400 -eq 0) {
            Write-Host $x 'is a leap year';

        else {
            Write-Host $x 'is not a leap year';
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Host $x 'is not a leap year';
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host $x 'is not a leap year';
}
```

Comment: "However, there seems to be something wrong" - *what* seems to be wrong (other than the missing closing `}` before the first `else`)? What are your expectations?

Comment: I cleaned up the code a bit so it's easier to see what went wrong. Pri 1: Readable code. Pri 2: Readable code ..... :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the fix. Just realized, the code posted has a missing parentheses but the console does not complains about it - rather it was throwing the year with both the results like $x is a leap year and also $x is not a leap year. I could have used the IsLeapYear function and was thinking what else would be in that function except for this code...I was successful using this in VB Script so thought I would write in PowerShell too. Well, I am relatively new to Powershell.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want :

```
[int]$x = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input a year : ';

If ($x % 4 -eq 0) {
    if ($x % 400 -eq 0){
        Write-Host $x 'is a leap year';
    }
    Elseif ($x % 100 -eq 0){
        Write-Host $x 'is not a leap year';
    }
    Else{
        Write-Host $x 'is a leap year';
    }
}
Else {
    Write-Host $x 'is not a leap year';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Mathias mentioned, you missing a closing curly bracket. However, you can still simplify your code a lot and nest your if statements like this:

```
[int]$x = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input a year : ';

if($x % 4 -eq 0 -and ($x % 400 -eq 0 -or $x % 100 -ne 0))
{
    Write-Host "$x is a leap year"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "$x is not a leap year"
}
```

Or just use:

```
[System.DateTime]::IsLeapYear($x)
```

Comment: Century years are NOT leap years UNLESS they can be evenly divided by 400. (For example, 1700, 1800, and 1900 were not leap years, but 1600 and 2000, which are divisible by 400, were.)

Comment: @jisaak correct if statement would be `if($x % 4 -eq 0 -and ($x % 400 -eq 0 -or $x % 100 -ne 0)){"leap year"}`

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I just wanted to show him how he can nest if statements with `-or` / `-and`. @AniMenon I corrected my answer...

Comment: No reason to reinvent the wheel. Use `IsLeapYear()`.  +1

Comment: if($x % 4 -eq 0 -and ($x % 400 -eq 0 -or $x % 100 -ne 0)){"leap year"}.
@Mathias - Thank you very much. I have learnt something very new. This one liner is simply good.